# Java - Update swing UI from outside the constructor

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm trying to update UI of my application made in Intellij each time the @Aftermethod is called. Inspecting the changeLable at run time my JFrame and panel etc are all null. I know I need to somehow pass or store the first reference and update that but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

```
public class TestUI
{

    public JPanel panel1;
    public JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    public JLabel progressText;
    public JProgressBar progressBar;
    public JButton button1;




    public TestUI(){


        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               updateUI();
            }
        });


    }

    public void changeLabel(String text){

        progressText.setText(text);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text app");
       frame.setContentPane(new TestUI().panel1);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);

    }


  @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){

        changeLabel("THIS SHOULD UPDATE GUI LABEL");

  }
```

Comment: *my panel etc are all null.* - correct, you never create an instance. All you do is define the variable:  `public JPanel panel1`. To create an instance you need to use the "new" keyword like you do when you create the JFrame.

Comment: When doing so JPanel panel1 loses all the styling from the intellij form and i have to panel.add(component)  for every element

Comment: When you run it as a test, `main` is never called so the form is never initialized. You may need to perform the initialization in `setUp` method.